# How to add more detail to an element in a dependent claim?

Tags: claims, claim-construction

I have a method of monitoring computers. In my independent claim I say `a network-connected device`. However in my dependent claim I specifically want to say that it is an application server. Is there a specific way to phrase that?

Will this work?

> The method of claim 1, further comprising the network-connected device of claim 1 be an application server.

Comment: Do you define "application server" in your specification?  There is not a standard definition in the field.  It could be any device that runs applications and reports information about them through a network.   if you intend to use a specific type of application server, then the disclosure should say so at the start.

Answer (score 2):

That wording is a little confusing in that a claim is either to a method or to a thing. Of course methods can involve things and sometimes things can be characterized by steps they perform. Without the framework of the wording of your claim 1 it is not 100% clear that the dependent claim you suggest would be proper.

If claim 1 is a well formed method claim, the dependent claim could be "The method of claim 1 where the network-connected device is an application server." This assumes the words "network-connected device" appear in claim 1 and claim is indeed a method claim. And that it is clear what application server means in the context of your application.

Many would use "wherein", I prefer the simpler "where".